# How to use Indexing in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, indexing, hive

I have written a **custom index handler** and wanted to test it. However hive is not using it. So I checked with simple table `(pokes (int foo, string bar))` which comes with hive distribution for testing purpose. Then I created a compact index and set the `set hive.optimize.index.filter=true;` However, upon checking the log info, it seems hive is still not using the index. So, what is the problem ? 
The query I issued is, `select foo from pokes WHERE foo=498`

Below is the log info I got after issuing the query.

```
12/07/26 12:25:17 INFO index.IndexWhereProcessor: Processing predicate for index optimization
12/07/26 12:25:17 INFO index.IndexWhereProcessor: (foo = 498) 

12/07/26 12:25:17 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: get_table : db=default tbl=pokes_idx

12/07/26 12:25:17 INFO hive.log: DDL: struct pokes_idx { i32 foo, string _bucketname, list<i64> _offsets}
12/07/26 12:25:17 INFO index.IndexWhereProcessor: checking index staleness...  
12/07/26 12:25:17 INFO index.IndexWhereProcessor: 1342465077455

12/07/26 12:25:17 INFO index.IndexWhereProcessor: 1342465077455

12/07/26 12:25:17 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library

12/07/26 12:25:17 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
```

Comment: can you find out what is hive.optimize.index.filter.compact.minsize valuse? This will stop hive using index.